# Cross database multiple records with join in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

In this case each person can be assigned to an unlimited number of companies. One of these assigned companies should always be the person's main company. As you can see in the SQL query which I have posted the ID of the person's main organization is stored in the column "main_company_id" in the "person" table.

I have database `Internal` on server `192.168.0.1` with `Person_Company Table` as given

```
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
| id | person_id | company_id | created_at |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
|  1 |      1005 |       2589 | 00:00:00   |
|  2 |      1006 |       2590 | 00:00:00   |
|  3 |      1007 |       2591 | 00:00:00   |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
```

`Person Table` is as given

```
+------+-------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  id  | name  |  phone  | main_company_id |     ref_id      |
+------+-------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1005 | John  | 0123456 |            2590 | 273722702297768 |
| 1006 | Doe   | 7894560 |            2591 | 955413080598021 |
| 1007 | Smith | 9517530 |            2589 | 164283934074454 |
+------+-------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

`Company Table` is as given

```
+------+-----------+---------+-----------------+
|  id  |   name    |   vat   |     ref_id      |
+------+-----------+---------+-----------------+
| 2589 | Company A | 0123456 | 540603005841231 |
| 2590 | Company B | 7894560 | 725472422399397 |
| 2591 | Company C | 9517530 | 367043795528136 |
+------+-----------+---------+-----------------+
```

Now there is another database `External` on the same server `192.168.0.1` with `External_Person` tables as given:

```
+----+-----------------+-------+----------------------+--------+
| id |     ref_id      | name  | internal_primary_key | gender |
+----+-----------------+-------+----------------------+--------+
|  1 | 273722702297768 | John  | ABC123456            | male   |
|  2 | 955413080598021 | Doe   | BCD456789            | female |
|  3 | 164283934074454 | Smith | DEF789456            | male   |
+----+-----------------+-------+----------------------+--------+
```

And another table on this `External` database is `External_Company`

```
+----+-----------------+-----------+----------------------+
| id |     ref_id      |   name    | internal_primary_key |
+----+-----------------+-----------+----------------------+
|  1 | 540603005841231 | Company A | XX4123456            |
|  2 | 725472422399397 | Company B | XX5456789            |
|  3 | 367043795528136 | Company C | XX6789456            |
+----+-----------------+-----------+----------------------+
```

What I want to achieve is like this result:

```
+----+------------+-------------+------------------+
| id | person_key | company_key | main_company_key |
+----+------------+-------------+------------------+
|  1 | ABC123456  | XX4123456   | XX5456789        |
|  2 | BCD456789  | XX5456789   | XX6789456        |
|  3 | DEF789456  | XX6789456   | XX4123456        |
+----+------------+-------------+------------------+
```

I have already achieved two columns through this statement:

```
SELECT EEP.internal_primary_key as Person_Key, EEC.internal_primary_key as Company_Key
FROM Internal.Person_Company as IPC
JOIN Internal.Person as IP on IP.id = IPC.person_id
JOIN Internal.Company as IC on IC.id = IPC.company_id
JOIN External.External_Person as EEP on IP.ref_id = EEP.ref_id
JOIN External.External_Company as EEC on IC.ref_id = EEC.ref_id
WHERE IPC.person_id = 1005;
```

And this has the output like this result:

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | person_key | company_key |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 | ABC123456  | XX4123456   |
|  2 | BCD456789  | XX5456789   |
|  3 | DEF789456  | XX6789456   |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

How can I get the main company's `internal_primary_key` of the person in this given scenario? How can I amend my this existing query to achieve the desired result which I have mentioned above?

Comment: In this join statement (`JOIN External.External_company as EEC on IC.ref_id = EEC.ref_id`), is your "c" uncapitalized? That would throw off your code if it is. It should be `JOIN External.External_Company as EEC on IC.ref_id = EEC.ref_id` if it isn't already.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, can you please get to my question in the end what I'm exactly looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this successfully after doing some research upon databases

```
SELECT EEP.internal_primary_key as Person_Key, EEC.internal_primary_key as Company_Key, MEEC.internal_primary_key as Main_Company_Key
FROM Internal.Person_Company as IPC
JOIN Internal.Person as IP on IP.id = IPC.person_id
JOIN Internal.Company as IC on IC.id = IPC.company_id
JOIN External.External_Person as EEP on IP.ref_id = EEP.ref_id
JOIN External.External_Company as EEC on IC.ref_id = EEC.ref_id
JOIN Internal.Company as MIC on MIC.id = IP.main_company_id
JOIN External.External_Company as MEEC on MIC.ref_id = MEEC.ref_id
WHERE IPC.person_id = 1005;
```

And now this results as I wanted:

```
+----+------------+-------------+------------------+
| id | person_key | company_key | main_company_key |
+----+------------+-------------+------------------+
|  1 | ABC123456  | XX4123456   | XX5456789        |
|  2 | BCD456789  | XX5456789   | XX6789456        |
|  3 | DEF789456  | XX6789456   | XX4123456        |
+----+------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? You have a lot of good work, it seems all you would need is add the `EEC.internal_primary_key as main_company_key` code to your select statement.

```
SELECT EEP.internal_primary_key as person_Key, EEC.internal_primary_key as company_Key, EEC.internal_primary_key as main_company_key
FROM Internal.Person_Company as IPC
JOIN Internal.Person as IP on IP.id = IPC.person_id
JOIN Internal.Company as IC on IC.id = IPC.company_id
JOIN External.External_Person as EEP on IP.ref_id = EEP.ref_id
JOIN External.External_Company as EEC on IC.ref_id = EEC.ref_id
WHERE IPC.person_id = 1005;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in this case I'm getting same record for both columns `company_key` and `main_company_key` I have already tried to do this.

Comment: So where is main_company_key supposed to be coming from?

Comment: I have added further description at the end of my query, please let me know if still there is something unclear to you.